# How to run a different html file when device width changes?

Tags: html, css

I am making my website responsive for different users, I know that I can use CSS when styling the website differently using CSS for example

```
`@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px){

{
body {
background: #ccc;
}
}`
```

However when my device reaches a width of 500px I want to run a different HTML file as the one image changes so that it is more suitable for mobile users. I think this is how to do it but if not please say otherwise.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with media queries, so why are you contemplating different html files?

Comment: Change the image size in css like everything else.

Comment: Is @LukeB not talking about providing different image files with optimised file sizes for different devices due to the loading times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two good ways:

**Picture Tag:**

---

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="smaller_landscape.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="smaller_portrait.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <source srcset="default_landscape.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="default_portrait.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <img srcset="default_landscape.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

**Image Tag:**

---

```
<img src="image-src.png" srcset="image-1x.png 1x, image-2x.png 2x,
                                 image-3x.png 3x, image-4x.png 4x">
```

Check Sample: [Picture](http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/) || [Image srcset](http://www.webkit.org/demos/srcset/)

One tricky way for changing images using css background url property and then load css differently for different media queries.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 901px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify3.css">
```